# Issue using meta_compare to remove 0 priced items from woocommerce low to high price sorting

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Background:**

I'm working on a site for a client and they would like the low-to-high price sorting to exclude $0/no-price items (these items require you to contact them for details).

**What I've Tried:**

I've used the woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args hook to modify the price sorting option, and I'm able to change some aspects of the sorting, and you can see the code below.

**The Issue:**

While the hook is getting called, and my function is firing and updating the args, it seems to be ignoring the meta_compare and meta_value options. When I set them to > and 0 or != and 0, or even = and 790 (the price of one of the items in the _price field in the wp_postmeta table) it's completely ignored.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {

    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

    if ('price' == $orderby_value){
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
        $args['meta_compare'] = '>';
        $args['meta_value'] = '0';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Edit: I came up with a solution for this and added it as an answer below.

Comment: Tracked from WPSE. Please don't swear. And be patient! I know it's frustrating, but your question was deemed off-topic (3rd party plugin). Nonetheless, I was keen to solve this one, and am looking into it right now.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic No need, I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the args aren't sent straight to the query in woocommerce, they're checked for then copied into the query, so the query only supports the args being used in the core.

For the time being, modifying the product_query() method in the plugin folder's /includes/wp-wc-query.php file, and adding:

```
$q->set( 'meta_compare', $ordering['meta_compare'] );
$q->set( 'meta_value', $ordering['meta_value'] );
```

Just after:

```
$q->set( 'orderby', $ordering['orderby'] );
$q->set( 'order', $ordering['order'] );
```

Allows me to set code in my question to filter out the items with no price.

I'm going to look for a way to do this without editing the plugin file (since it will break when the plugin gets updated) and I'll update this if I find a better way.

Edit:

To make the change permanent without having to edit the plugin files, I came up with and added the following to my client's functions.php file:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_sort_for_low_to_high');
function custom_sort_for_low_to_high($q) {
    if($q->query_vars['meta_key'] == '_price'){
        $q->query_vars['meta_compare'] = '>';
        $q->query_vars['meta_value'] = '0';
    }
    return $q;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The working solution in 2023 is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'zero_price_products' );
function zero_price_products( $q ){
    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
    if($q->query_vars['orderby'] == 'price' && $q->query_vars['order'] == 'ASC') {
            $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => '_price',
            'value'     => 0,
            'compare'   => '>'
        );
        $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
```